# Open port in firewall on Catalina

Tags: network, catalina, firewall

I'm trying to run a Kibana (from Elastic) server on an old Mac Mini on my local network. The Kibana instance is running successfully and I can access the UI locally and also from another machine on the network if I disable the firewall on the Mini. But I would prefer not to disable the firewall but rather open just the one port (5601 in this case).
Normally when I run a process I get a popup asking if I want to allow incoming connections for that process but when I start Kibana no such popup appears. I have tried adding the node binary (in <kibana_root>/node/bin/node) to the firewall preferences pane to allow incoming connections but it doesn't help any.
I've also tried applying what is written here: https://blog.neilsabol.site/post/quickly-easily-adding-pf-packet-filter-firewall-rules-macos-osx/ using pfctl but that is also not helping any.

Can someone please point me in the right direction of how I could open port 5601 for the Kibana process? I'm running Catalina 10.15.7

Thanks very much.